# Embedded error: String index out of range: 70

Tags: java, maven-2

I have Maven 2.2.1, JDK 1.6.0_26 on Linux Ubuntu.
I i use maven-jar-plugin version 2.3.2 
When i try to build project with maven2, i have error:

**Embedded error: String index out of range: 70**

Whats may be wrong?
It always builds, but not today.

In root pom i have configuration

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>

    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifestEntries>
                <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                <Buildserver-projectname>${job.name}</Buildserver-projectname>
                <Build-number>${buildserver.buildnumber}</Build-number>
                <Revision-number>${svn.revision.number}</Revision-number>
                <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                <Build-time>${buildTime}</Build-time>
                <!-- Don`t change  Implementation-Vendor because it use in sufd java class-->
                <Implementation-Vendor>Integration Systems</Implementation-Vendor>
                <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                <Implementation-Version>${implementation.version}</Implementation-Version>
                <Implementation-Title>${project.description}</Implementation-Title>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 70
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1934)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest$Attribute.writeLine(Manifest.java:388)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest$Attribute.writeValue(Manifest.java:370)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest$Attribute.write(Manifest.java:344)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest$Section.write(Manifest.java:588)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest.write(Manifest.java:1079)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver.writeManifest(JarArchiver.java:363)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver.initZipOutputStream(JarArchiver.java:298)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain(AbstractZipArchiver.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute(AbstractZipArchiver.java:211)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:875)
    at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive(MavenArchiver.java:543)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.AbstractJarMojo.createArchive(AbstractJarMojo.java:216)
    ... 20 more

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code of org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest it looks like it could be encoding problem. They first do string.substring(0,x) and then string.getBytes().length > x which looks very suspicious.

Try to convert your files to ascii and see what you get.

Comment: Yup, seems some of the processing could be based on byte length instead of character length: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-70?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab. Probably best to convert the manifest first and see if that works. Unless the asker doesn't have a custom manifest and the error occurs during generation. That could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify the code, I can only guess what might have gone wrong. The error messages says the error is cause by invoke substring(int) or substring(int, int). Code like this could invoke that error:

```
String str = "I like cats.";
String favoriteObject = str.substring(7, 13);
```

Looking at this code, you probably made the mistake of over-exaggerating the endIndex in the substring method.

If you're looking into splitting a string based off of characters, consider using `String.indexOf(char)`.

For more information regarding Strings, check the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: It is not my code i only use maven to build jar in my project.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to compare the actual revision of you whole project with your latest one that worked. So you see which files (MANIFEST.MF?) have changed. I assume one of the pom files got changed or the checkout from the repository used the wrong file encoding (this time).

(fixed a typo)

Answer (score 0):

That's a Plexus Archiver bug with treating all encodings as single byte (which isn't true for UTF-8):

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-70

Fixed in plexus-archiver-2.1 by this patch:

http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/37210/PLXCOMP-70.patch